# Promise loop leaks memory

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, recursion, promise

I'm trying to page through my database, which involves using results from each query to start the next query.

When I write the query with a `while` loop, as suggested in [this article](https://alexn.org/blog/2017/10/11/javascript-promise-leaks-memory.html#the-non-leaky-solution), my memory grows by almost a hundred megabytes per second, despite me aggregating but a small amount of data.

```
let startKey = null;
while (true) {
    global.gc();
    let results = (await pouch.find({
        selector: {
            type: 'app',
            appId: {$gt: startKey},
        },
        fields: ['appId'],
        limit: 50,
        use_index: 'byAppId'
    })).docs;
    // Do some work...
    if (results.length === 0) return;
    startKey = results[results.length - 1].appId;
```

If I follow the same article's advice to use Bluebird, I also see huge memory growth:

```
function doStuff(startKey, acc) {
    global.gc();
    return BPromise.resolve(
        pouch.find({
            selector: {
                type: 'app',
                appId: {$gt: startKey},
            },
            fields: ['appId'],
            limit: 50,
            use_index: 'byAppId'
        })
    ).then(({docs}) => {
        if (docs.length === 0) return acc;
        return doStuff(
            startKey = docs[docs.length - 1].appId,
            acc + docs.length
        )
    });
}
await Promise.resolve(doStuff(null, 0));
}
```

Dev Tools' heap allocation timeline shows everything gets garbage collected very quickly and there's little heap growth. Yet the process' memory grows rapidly.
[image: heap allocation timeline]

Heap snapshots also show allocation deltas of only KB, when my process' memory has grown by well over 1GB between snapshots.
[image: heap snapshots]

Comment: Just because memory grows it does not mean it's a memory leak. It's okay if memory grows in languages with automatic memory management. What is your real problem?

Comment: is `results.length === 0` ever true?

Comment: It is a memory leak if the memory never gets released at some later time. Is that what you are seeing? If the memory frees some time after the loop / bluebird method finishes then you don't have a leak. you just created a sequence of code that keeps the GC from freeing memory during its execution

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, results.length does become 0

Comment: @zerkms No part of my program is accumulating data as the code loops. Provided I wrote my code correctly, my memory usage should not grow from iteration to iteration.

Comment: Does my program have some obvious data accumulation that I can't spot? I don't see why memory usage would grow _at all_, regardless of how often it GCs, since I'm not assigning more than a single string+number to variables or capturing data in long-lived closures or performing a kind of recursion that would grow the call stack.

Comment: @spiffytech "grow at all" --- you fetch data from a remote resource, it is stored in memory. `pouch.find` internally also uses memory with no doubts. And every other function/language construct in your code.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was confused because I immediately dereference the data in every iteration. I've updated my code to explicitly garbage collect, and I still see the memory usage growing.

Comment: Take a heapdump, wait some time, take another one. Then take google chrome and compare them. Also `global.gc(true);`

Comment: "when my process' memory has grown by well over 1GB between snapshots. "--- obtaining "how much memory process uses" is an extremely tricky problem. How do you get it?

Comment: What’s `pouch`? Is it maybe doing some caching?

Comment: @Ry- we have heapdumps already - the delta of allocated memory is low. OP has problems somewhere else.

Comment: Try to rewrite without recursion, just to see what happens to memory.  `while(true)` is a recipe for disaster in my experience. How large is the data itself?? Also, calling garbage collection should never be necessary and only proves that you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Is this the complete code? What is `// Do some work...`?

Comment: Did you ever find out what this was?